# How to read AddressOfEntryPoint in memory

Tags: reverse-engineering, malware, ida

I am working to analyze malware, this malware try to write a new file to other process. they save the data of the new file in memory start with MZ.
how I can know the address of entry point for the PE file in memory?

Comment: if you can provide more details, please ask this question on the stack exchange [reverse engineering site](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/). Several professional malware analysts answer malware analysis questions there. We would love to have more malware questions

Answer (score 1):

Find below way to find address of entry point as well as to read various header parameters.

```
LPCSTR fileName; //exe file to parse
HANDLE hFile; 
HANDLE hFileMapping;
LPVOID lpFileBase;
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader;
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS peHeader;

hFile = CreateFileA(fileName,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);

if(hFile==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    printf("\n CreateFile failed in read mode \n");
    return 1;
}

hFileMapping = CreateFileMapping(hFile,NULL,PAGE_READONLY,0,0,NULL);

if(hFileMapping==0)
{
    printf("\n CreateFileMapping failed \n");
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return 1;
}

lpFileBase = MapViewOfFile(hFileMapping,FILE_MAP_READ,0,0,0);

if(lpFileBase==0)
{
    printf("\n MapViewOfFile failed \n");
    CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return 1;
}

dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER) lpFileBase;  //pointer to dos headers

if(dosHeader->e_magic==IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
{
    //if it is executable file print different fileds of structure
    //dosHeader->e_lfanew : RVA for PE Header
    printf("\n DOS Signature (MZ) Matched");

    //pointer to PE/NT header
    peHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS) ((u_char*)dosHeader+dosHeader->e_lfanew);

    if(peHeader->Signature==IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
    {
        printf("\n PE Signature (PE) Matched \n");

        //address of entry point
        //peHeader->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint

    }
    UnmapViewOfFile(lpFileBase);
    CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return 0;
}
else
{
    printf("\n DOS Signature (MZ) Not Matched \n");
    UnmapViewOfFile(lpFileBase);
    CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return 1;
}
```